# Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating the

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating the region in the 1st quadrant enclosed by $$y = \frac{1}{11} x\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ y = x^{1/3}$$ about the y-axis.

Comment: Is y = x/11 ? and y = cube root of x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of closure on the result, I'm working out the numerical values by both the "disk method", which **Semsem** set up, and by the "shell method".

The "bounding functions" can be expressed as $ \ x = 11y \ $ and $ \ x = y^3 \ $ for applying "disks" (integration in the $ y-$ direction).  The intersection points of the curves are given by

$$ \frac{1}{11}x \ - \ x^{1/3} \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^{1/3} \ (\frac{1}{11}x^{2/3} \ - \ 1 ) \ = \ 0 \ , $$

so we have either $ \ x = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ y = 0 \ \ $ or $  \ \ x^{2/3} = 11 \ \Rightarrow \ x = 11^{3/2} \ \Rightarrow \ y = 11^{1/2} \ . $  The volume integral **Semsem** shows is then evaluated as

$$ \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{11^2}{3} y^3 \ - \ \frac{1}{7}y^7 \ \right]_0^{11^{1/2}} \ = \  \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{11^2}{3} \cdot (11^{1/2})^3 \ - \ \frac{1}{7} \cdot (11^{1/2})^7 \ - \ 0\ \right]  $$

$$ = \  \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{11^2}{3} \cdot (11^{3/2}) \ - \ \frac{1}{7} \cdot (11^{7/2})  \right] \ = \ \pi \  (11^{7/2})\  \left(  \frac{1}{3} \ - \ \frac{1}{7}   \right) \ = \ \frac{4 \pi}{21} \cdot  (11^{7/2}) \ ,  $$

which may also be written as $ \ \frac{4 \ \cdot \ 11^3 \ \cdot \ \pi}{21} \cdot  (11^{1/2}) \ $ or $ \ \frac{5324 \  \pi}{21} \sqrt{11} \ . $

Applying the "shell method" instead, which involves an integration in the $ x-$ direction, the "radius arm" extending from the axis of rotation, the $ \ y-$ axis, is $ \ r = x \ , $ and the height of the shells is given by $ \ x^{1/3} - \frac{1}{11}x \ . $  Here, the volume integral is

$$ 2 \pi \ \int_0^{11^{3/2}}  \ x \ (x^{1/3} \ - \ \frac{1}{11}x) \ \ dx \ = \ 2 \pi \ \int_0^{11^{3/2}}  \ x^{4/3} \ - \ \frac{1}{11}x^2 \ \ dx   $$

$$ = \ 2 \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{3}{7} y^{7/3} \ - \ \frac{1}{33}y^3 \ \right]_0^{11^{1/2}} \ = \  2 \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{3}{7} \cdot (11^{3/2})^{7/3} \ - \ \frac{1}{33} \cdot (11^{3/2})^3 \ - \ 0\ \right]  $$

$$ = \  2 \pi \ \left[ \ \frac{3}{7} \cdot (11^{7/2}) \ - \ \frac{1}{3 \cdot 11} \cdot (11^{9/2})  \right] \ = \ 2 \pi \  (11^{7/2})\  \left(  \frac{3}{7} \ - \ \frac{1}{3}   \right) \ = \ \frac{4 \pi}{21} \cdot  (11^{7/2})   $$

once again; the decimal expression is indeed $ \ \approx \ 2641.587 \ . $  So the result **Andy** shows in his comment looks to be correct; it is unclear from what is said here why he believed it to be otherwise.  (Perhaps this was a case of a textbook answer written in a different but equivalent form, or a computer-based system rejecting the way the answer was typed...)

Answer (score 1):

$$V=\pi\int_0^\sqrt{11}(11y)^2-(y^3)^2dy$$

Comment: So I get an answer of (5324 sqrt(11) * pi) / 21 ~
2641.6 But this is incorrect.

Comment: your calculations are incorrect

Comment: And thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Uh do find it correct